# Side Menu Compatibility Issues for IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

My left side navigation menu does not seem to show up on IE7. However on the newer versions they do. Can someone help me on this? I am not allowed to upload any screenshots Please let me know if you need me to input any code to help provide info for this problem. The website is www.firstlook-electronics.com. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Arshad

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have set `.col-1` css to be `overflow:hidden`. Set overflow to visible in ie7 and the left menu appears.